# Why is the overflow not executed in the textarea?

Tags: javascript

In the following example, I try to write horizontally beyond the text box. The lines are very long, so a scrollbar should be created. Something is not working, can someone help me? Thanks.

I have another incomplete code in it that I'm still working on. It's about a line and a time counter.

Regarding the line writer, I've noticed that the computer is getting slower as many lines are written. Is it necessary that here constantly should be deleted the memory?

```js
var btnWrite = document.getElementById("writeElement");
var btnStop = document.getElementById("stopElement");
var btnClear = document.getElementById("clearElement");

btnWrite.addEventListener("click", writeData);
btnStop.addEventListener("click", stopText);
btnClear.addEventListener("click", clearText);

textareaStatus = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('textarea'));

var timer = null;

function writeData() {
  var Text = ("1111111111" + " " + "2222222222" + " " + "3333333333" + " " + "4444444444" + " " + "5555555555" + " " + "6666666666" + " " + "7777777777" + "\n");
  timer = setTimeout(writeData, 1000);
  textareaStatus.value += Text;
  startTimer();
}

function stopText() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  //stopTimer();
}

function clearText() {
  textareaStatus.value = '';
  clearTimer();
}

function count() {
  newLines = (this).val().split("\n").length;
  linesUsed.text(newLines);
}

function startTimer() {

  var sec = 0;

  function pad(val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
  }
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    //document.getElementById("tenthsseconds").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec/60,100));
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
  }, 1000);
};

function stopTimer() {}

function clearTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  //timer = '';
}
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  font-size: small;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 510px;
  height: 140px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="writeElement">Write</button>
<button id="stopElement">Stop</button>
<button id="clearElement">Clear</button>

<div class="count">Lines used: <span id="linesUsed">0</span>
  <div>

    <span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tenthsseconds">00</span>
```

Comment: Your **browser** will get slower as more lines are logged in the textarea because its continually writing to that object in the DOM.

Comment: I have never seen a textarea that has horizontal scroll. Use a different element for that like `<pre>`

Comment: ***@charlietfl*** Thanks for the Tip, do you think instead of <style>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to stop your lines from breaking to the next line

Use [`overflow: auto;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to automatically add the scrollbars where needed.

```
textarea {
  display: block;
  font-size: small;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 510px;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: black;
}
```

---

### Example

```js
var btnWrite = document.getElementById("writeElement");
var btnStop = document.getElementById("stopElement");
var btnClear = document.getElementById("clearElement");

btnWrite.addEventListener("click", writeData);
btnStop.addEventListener("click", stopText);
btnClear.addEventListener("click", clearText);

textareaStatus = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('textarea'));

var timer = null;

function writeData() {
  var Text = ("1111111111" + " " + "2222222222" + " " + "3333333333" + " " + "4444444444" + " " + "5555555555" + " " + "6666666666" + " " + "7777777777" + "\n");
  timer = setTimeout(writeData, 1000);
  textareaStatus.value += Text;
  startTimer();
}

function stopText() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  //stopTimer();
}

function clearText() {
  textareaStatus.value = '';
  clearTimer();
}

function count() {
  newLines = (this).val().split("\n").length;
  linesUsed.text(newLines);
}

function startTimer() {

  var sec = 0;

  function pad(val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
  }
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    //document.getElementById("tenthsseconds").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec/60,100));
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
  }, 1000);
};

function stopTimer() {}

function clearTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  //timer = '';
}
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  font-size: small;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 510px;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="writeElement">Write</button>
<button id="stopElement">Stop</button>
<button id="clearElement">Clear</button>

<div class="count">Lines used: 
  <span id="linesUsed">0</span>
<div>

<span id="minutes">00</span>:
<span id="seconds">00</span>:
<span id="tenthsseconds">00</span>
```

In regards to your second question:

> Regarding the line writer, I've noticed that the computer is getting
>   slower as many lines are written. Is it necessary that here constantly
>   should be deleted the memory?

Your **browser** will get slower as more lines are logged in the textarea because its continually writing to that object in the DOM.

---

### P.S.

As an aside to my answer, I have to agree with charlietfl when he mentions the use of other elements to achieve this functionality. [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) is definitely a good alternative.

You should also think about clearing down some of the text thats filling up the value of your element in the [`DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) over time.

Comment: thanks for the answers, white-space nowrap; write me everything on one line. The goal is to write line by line. Each line should be written below. Because they are long, they must override the horizontal area otherwise they will be cut off.

Comment: Because of the second question: Can the DOM be cleaned up continuously?

Comment: ***@Master Yoda*** I put "\ n" at the end of the line, but whitespace: nowrap ignores it. Is there a solution to create the line break?

Comment: @JaDoLo Maybe your browser doesn't support `white-space`. Try `word-wrap: break-word;` as an alternative. The DOM can be cleaned up as you go along, however your problem involves having to clear down the **value** of a textarea as it grows. I suppose you could clear down a set amount of characters once you hit a limit but it kind of goes against the point of writing a log.

Comment: ***@Master Yoda*** I thank you for your answer. I tested that, but it does the opposite of what I'm looking for. Instead of breaking the values at the edge of the textarea, the line should continue to be written to the end.  So beyond the limitation of the textarea, to the end of the line ("\n"). Only then should the line break be made.

Comment: ***@Master Yoda*** Because of the DOM problem. The content of the textarea should not be deleted, as these values will all be used sequentially later. These are spatial coordinates for controlling. Everything else that is not in the textarea is not needed and can be deleted. Otherwise I have to find another way to realize that. Another solution might be to write the data into the temp and transfer it to the textarea only at the end of the recording process. What do you think ?

Comment: Then im really confused as white-space: nowrap; should work fine for what you need. What specific browser are you using? Writing to a temporary file and then putting it back into the textarea doesn't solve the problem, it will still dump all of the text back into the element in the DOM. I would recommend outputting all of the data to an external text file instead of trying to showing it on screen. Either that or log it to the browser console instead.

Comment: I work with the latest Firefox, white-space: nowrap; does not make a line break but writes all in a row on a single line. But you're right, Chrome is doing it right !! I just tested that.

Comment: The goal is for the recording process to proceed at full speed without hindrance. If it is stopped, the data will be exported to an external text file. I have to use the textarea only to provide the collected data for export.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show scroll bar on x axis, you should set

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

In your text-area. Currently you have both

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

The second one is overriding the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already tried, it does not succeed.

Comment: ***@Mikey*** They are certainly right. I thought of the same as that, only horizontally. [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow_xy)